# Somebody know how can i check if i'm in home page in moodle?

Tags: moodle

I try put the next code in the header

```
 <a class="logo" href="<?php echo preg_replace("(https?:)", "", $CFG->wwwroot); ?>" title="<?php print_string('home'); ?>"></a>
                    <div id="course_name">
                        <?php
                        if ($home) {echo "hello";}
                        else{$coursename = $PAGE->course->fullname;
                        echo $coursename;
                        echo $home;
                        }

                        ?>
                    </div>
```

But not work, I use moodle 2.7

Thanks.

Comment: $courseid = $PAGE->course->id;
    if ($courseid==1)

Answer (score 1):

`if ($home)` is a Moodle 1.9 thing. The function you're looking for (which would work in 2.7) is an `isset()`. Like so:

```
<?php
        if (isset($PAGE) && (strpos($PAGE->pagetype, 'site-') === 0)) {
           echo "You are on the home page";
        }

        else {
           echo "You are not on the homepage";
        }

?>
```